# HostListner with particular element in the template Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My requirement is I want to fix the table header after certain scroll to up,while the table body is scrolling.

My app.html is below.

```
  <table class="table table-fixed-ok" #scroller  [class.fixed]="fixed">
                      <thead >
                          <tr class="row-hor-heading">
                              <th colspan="3" scope="row"><span class="bank-name">
                           {{offer.name}}</span>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr class="row-2-data bg-white">

                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

So i want to listen the scroll of this table only(app.html contains many more other div.i want this div scroll to be listened.)

My app.ts section is below

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
     onWindowScroll(event: Event) {
     debugger;
     let num = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.table-fixed-ok').scrollTop;
     if ( num >50 ) {
            this.fixed = true;
          }else if (this.fixed && num < 5) {
           this.fixed = false;
          }
}
```

But this is not working as i needed.While printing the num variable always giving 0.And also it is triggering whole whole body scrolling.How to solve this.Please give me a solution.

Comment: Why don't you just add `(scroll)="scrollHandler($event)"` to the element where you want to listen to?

Comment: Then what should i write in the scrollHandler($event) function??

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why would you write something different in the scroll handler?

Comment: I wrote scroll function.

Comment: After that i wrote the function in .ts file

Comment: But nothing is happening while scroll

Comment: Then you probably added the binding on the wrong element. The event is only emitted by the container element which gets its content scrolled, not any element that is scrolled for example. If you can create a http://stackblitz.com I can have another look.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmm8zs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Here what i want is .We will scroll the table after some scroll to top the Axis bank that is the table header should be fixed and the table data should get scrolled

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify an element for `@HostListener()`, but you can just apply the event binding to the element directly like:

```
<div (scroll)="myScrollHandler($event)"
```

Comment: in that function what should i write??